# web application using angular 8 and loopback 4

Tags: angular, loopback4

i have developed and deployed web applications using mean stack(using angular 8 version). Now i want to shift to loopback for the backend. The new release version of loopback (loopback 4) does not contain any documentation on how to connect angular 8 project with loopback 4.
In the documentation of loopback 3, it is mentioned to intall angular angular-resource angular-ui-router bootstrap. But i got the angular version 1.

here is my package.json

```
    "angular": "^1.7.9",
    "angular-resource": "^1.7.9",
    "angular-ui-router": "^1.0.23",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1"
```

My found many tutorials on angular and loopback. but all of those are does'nt provided me the solution.
someone please help me how to use angular 8 in loopback 4 project and how to deploy the same.

Comment: Well, it's not possible for the loopback teams to document how to connect all the possible clients. I guess your front end app communicates to your back end using REST API. Simple use Loopback documentation on building REST API and Angulars documentation for consuming it.

Comment: @B45i, i understand what you said, but what i have to do during the time of deployment. how to run angular app and loopback4 app on one port. and how to combine both the node dependencies(angular and loopback) into one package.json file

Comment: why don't you maintain  front end and back end separately? If you want to expose them on same port, use `nginx` or `apache`